# How to disable captions in Youtube Android API?

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I'm using [YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) from [Youtube Android API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/%20and%20I%20want%20to%20disable%20captions%20in%20my%20player.). But I didn't find option for disabling captions inside player. that's equivalent of cc_load_policy and iv_load_policy. Is there a solution for turning them off.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 4.4, close captioning is a System feature.
You can redirect the user on the corresponding settings page :

```
startActivityForIntent(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CAPTIONING_SETTINGS));
```

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCRGc2PcmB8)